# What does the phrase "swoop into" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase "swoop into" in the following sentence:

> You can use the app’s amazing flight tracking function to perfectly time when the flight will **swoop into** your frame.

The text is from a flight information app.

Comment: Have you looked up the definition of “[swooped”/“swoop](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/swoop)” and what did you find that confused you?

Answer (score -1):

There is no phrase "swoop into" in the sentence. There are two distinct parts:

> action: **(will) swoop**

and

> location (where will it swoop?): **into your frame**